# Golang. Ошибка "[]byte does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)"

Tags: golang

```golang
base, err := ioutil.ReadFile("base.txt")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

io.WriteString(base, "it works!")
```

Ошибка: `cannot use base (type []byte) as type io.Writer in argument to io.WriteString: []byte does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)`

Comment: А в чём собственно вопрос? У байтового слайса действительно нет метода Write. Поясните, какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Я хочу записать в файл строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код

```golang
// открыть файл для чтения и скопировать его содержимое в слайс
// присвоить адрес слайса вашей переменной base
base, err := ioutil.ReadFile("base.txt")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// ошибка: вы пытаететь записать строку в слайс
io.WriteString(base, "it works!")
```

Что вы хотите

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // открываем или создаем файл для чтения и записи
    // возвращаем указатель на структуру *os.File и присваиваем base его значение
    base, err := os.OpenFile("base.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer base.Close()

    // base удовлетворяет интерфейс io.Writer что позволяет 
    // io.WriteString использовать base для записи
    _, err = io.WriteString(base, "it works!")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```